# weekOfYear not working

Tags: ios, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I recently updated Xcode to version 6.0, and when I did so, I was warned that the `NSDateComponents` `week` method was deprecated, and the new `weekOfYear` method replaces it. I believe these methods should return the week ordinal of the year, between 1 and 52. But the value that I get with `weekOfYear` is way beyond 52.

The code that I used to test this is below. Can someone please verify this for me, and if I am doing something wrong, please tell me what that is?

```
- (void)testWeekOfYearMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Inside testWeekOfYearMethod...");

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

    //NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    NSInteger weekOrdinal = [weekdayComponents weekOfYear];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"];

    NSString *formattedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"In getWeekContainingDate(), Date: %@ has week %ld", formattedString, [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:weekOrdinal] integerValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`weekOfYear` is just a accessing the corresponding part of the `NSDateComponents` you have created. Your example does not specify the option `NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit`, so it has nothing to access!

Add that to your options and you should get the result you are expecting:

`NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];`